# Keeping score (variables) even if moving to next page

Tags: javascript, single-page-application

I'm a webdev teacher for students who are going to build an educational app for the rules for vessels navigating. So it's a bunch of exercises they will animate with GSAP(probably). The user have to click a button to choose the correct navigation, if correct the score updates. I would like to implement a score keeper that keep tracks of the total result viewed to the user even if the user moves forward to the next  animated exercise. What is the simplest way of doing this. Localstorage? My students are in high school, so start using a Javascript framework is over the time limit of the web development course.

Comment: Yes, localstorage is the most simple solution, but if it's really a *single*-page-application I don't really see how the could move to the *next* page at all…

Comment: More precise: Change between scenes

Comment: In that case, you probably don't need a local/session storage at all - just a global variable will do. (There's not much difference in using them, though)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, web storage ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)) is how you would do this. `localStorage` if the values should be persistent across sessions, `sessionStorage` if not.